# Creating subfolders in Mailcore2 with Gmail

Tags: ios, objective-c, imap, mailcore2

I followed the thread on github here: https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/issues/321

And subsequently used the following code below:

```
MCOIMAPFetchNamespaceOperation * op = [session fetchNamespaceOperation];
[op start:^(NSError * error, NSDictionary * namespaces) {
    if (error != nil)
        return;
    MCOIMAPNamespace * ns = [namespaces objectForKey:MCOIMAPNamespacePersonal];
    NSString * path = [ns pathForComponents:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"test", @"sub1", nil]];
    MCOIMAPOperation * createOp = [session createFolderOperation:path];
    [createOp start:^(NSError * error) {
    }];

    path = [ns pathForComponents:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"test", @"sub2", nil]];
    createOp = [session createFolderOperation:path];
    [createOp start:^(NSError * error) {
    }];

    path = [ns pathForComponents:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"test", @"sub3", nil]];
    createOp = [session createFolderOperation:path];
    [createOp start:^(NSError * error) {
    }];
}];
```

However, when I log onto my Desktop Gmail account, I see that the folder structure looks like this:

[image: On GMail]

Rather than a subfolder structure I would expect, e.g., Mailbox:

[image]

Am I doing something or is this an error with Mailcore2?

EDIT: Answer is to create the parent folder first, then the subfolders.

Comment: Did you create a "test" folder for these to be subfolders of?

Comment: No. That was the problem. D'oh!

Answer (score 1):

Create a "test" folder first, for those to be subfolders of.

Otherwise you are left with a "virtual" test folder, which in the case of gmail web ui, will show with slashes instead.